# How many solutions $x(t)$ of this ODE satisfy $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}x(t) =0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I don't know how to solve the following problem. How many solutions of $$x^{\prime}(t) = x(t) -e^{-t^2}$$ satisfy the conditions
$\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}x(t) =0$?
Should I look for some explicit formula? Can someone give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution of homogeneous equation is
$$
x(t) = Ce^{t}.
$$
Now let $C = C(t)$. Then we obtain an equation on $C(t)$:
$$
C'(t)e^{t} = -e^{-t^2}
$$
or
$$
C'(t) = -e^{-t^2-t} = -e^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}.
$$
So
$$
C(t) = c - \sqrt[4]{e}\int_0^te^{-\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}du
$$
or
$$
C(t) = c - \sqrt[4]{e}\int_0^{t+\frac{1}{2}}e^{- u^2}du.
$$
Finally we get
$$
x(t) = ce^t - e^{t+\frac14}\int_0^{t+\frac{1}{2}}e^{- u^2}du.
$$

When $t \to \pm\infty$ the integral
$$
\int_0^{t+\frac{1}{2}}e^{- u^2}du
$$
is bounded. So the asymptotic behaviour of $x(t)$ is the one of $Me^t$. When $t \to -\infty$ $x(t) \to 0$ anyway. When $t \to +\infty$
$$
x(t) \to
\left\{\begin{align*}
+\infty, &\quad M > 0\\
0, &\quad M = 0\\
-\infty, &\quad M < 0
\end{align*}\right. .
$$

The expression for $M$ is
$$
M = c - e^{\frac14}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{- u^2}du.
$$

Comment: Awsome! Thanks a lot, very clear, very useful

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is $$
x(t) = Ce^t  - \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}e^{t + 1/4} \operatorname{erf}\left( {t + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right).
$$ Since $\mathop {\lim }\nolimits_{t \to  \pm \infty } \operatorname{erf}\left( {t + \frac{1}{2}} \right) =  \pm 1$ with a rate of about $e^{-t^2}$, the only particular solution that satisfies the requirement is the one with $C=\frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}e^{1/4}$: $$
x(t) = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}e^{t + 1/4} \operatorname{erfc}\left( {t + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit at $-\infty$ is trivial. The linear nature gives an affine linear dependence for large $t$ of $x(t)$ on $x(0)$. Hand-waving one can say that between the solutions diverging to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ for $t\to+\infty$, there has to be one converging to $0$.

However, that is not really certain, you can only make that precise with the solution formula.

Comment: May i ask why is it trivial? and why do we have the affine dependence?

Comment: Trivial: Because largely proportional to $e^{t}$, which goes to zero for $t\to-\infty$. And the solution of a linear DE depends (affine) linearly on the initial conditions.